# Using custom login page in Salesforce experience with SSO

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I'm not entirely sure this is possible.  We have a Salesforce digital experience with a custom login page.  It works fine logging into our digital experience.  Is it possible to configure/create a login page that will work as an SSO identity provider from a third-party site?

This means a user is on a third-party site, is redirected to a site login page with SSO info, log in, and are redirected back to the third-party site with all the auth info.

We want to use the site registration page and login page if possible.